# Do previous declarations in C change how pointers are initialized?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, initialization

How are pointers in C initialized? It seems like previous declarations change how they are initialized.

Consider the following example:

```
int *a;
printf("a: %p\n", (void*)a);
```

This code snippet results in

```
a: (nil)
```

So one could think that variables at function start are initialized with null, but if I execute this code:

```
int *a;
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    int *b;
    printf("a: %p\n", (void*)a);
    printf("b: %p", (void*)b);
}
```

This is the result:

```
a: 0x7ffff3bb2e40
b: (nil)
```

How can I determine how the variables are initialized?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: The pointer either has some random value or is zeroed, depending on how it is declared.

Comment: You can determine if the variable is initialized or not based on where its definition occurs in the program (and whether it's marked static or extern)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are not assigning an initial value, it depends on what there is on the memory beforehand. So there are two possibilities

- Garbage. Indeterminate values which come from a previous execution or status, etc...this l yields an undefined behaviour.
- Initialization during startup. It is quite common to initialize to zero some segments of memory such us the `bss` segment during the startup (before `main()`). In this case, you are not initializating the variable, you are initializating the bunch of memory in which the variable is allocated, anyway, this won't yield an undefined behaviour.

Edited for accuracy due to M.M 's comment.

Answer (score 1):

If a pointer is defined at file scope, it is initialized to NULL.

If it is defined at block scope, the pointer is **uninitialized**, so it could have any random value, including NULL.

Comment: uninitialized variables have *indeterminate value*, not any random value.  The value could appear to change by itself between inspections, compare unequal with itself, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> How are pointers in C initialized?

In C, local pointers (in [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)) are ***not* initialized** unless you code *explicitly* their initialization. You have an **undefined behavior**. Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

The only pointers which are *implicitly* initialized are those in global or `static` variables (so called file scope variables). In practice, such pointers are initialized to all zero bits, which usually means the `NULL` pointer.

In practice, with a modern compiler like a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), you should enable all warnings and debug info (e.g. compile with `gcc  -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then you'll get warnings. Improve your code to have none.